# What does ward No mean

Tags: meaning

There is an item called "ward no" on my prescription record card from an hospital. What does it mean or what does it refer to?

```
ward no | ward name
---------------------
   6       Bracken               <--- on one card 
---------------------
   8       Meavy                 <---- on another card
```

There are several items, like "pat no" refers to patient number.
But I am not sure what ward number means.

Comment: It's probably an abbreviation of "ward number", did you get the prescription record card from a hospital?

Comment: I agree with the other comments. Could you post a photo of this part of the form (with personal information blocked out of course)?

Comment: Your question lacks details and context. Where, on the record card does it say "ward no"? What else does it say on the card? What words/phrases are close to "ward no" on the cad? Is there a full stop after "no"?

Comment: Edit shows the card also records "ward **name**", which makes it pretty obvious to me. But this is clerical record-keeping and administration, not "use of English" as covered by this site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am guessing it is an abbreviation?

Comment: I just googled **"bracken ward" "meavy ward"**, to discover these are the names of 2 wards at Plymouth hospital. But you must have *got* the cards from that hospital, so you should have already known that. ***No.*** is an abbreviation for ***Number***, and it doesn't *always* include the full stop.

Comment: "No" or "No." is short for "number", as shown on [this table](http://www.technologyuk.net/computing/software-development/systems-analysis/images/rda01.gif).

Comment: Oh, please, it can only mean "ward number".

Comment: It is a short way of writing 'number' but is actually an abbreviation of the French word for number which is 'numero'. That explains the 'o'. You sometimes see 'num' which _is_ an abbreviation of 'number'

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, No. is a common abbreviation for "number".

Having done a little online research I have the following suggestion.

In some hospitals (especially private hospitals) each patient may be assigned a separate room. Presumably each room on such a ward needs a separate number.

Therefore I conclude that this is effectively an address, i.e.

*Room Number 6, Bracken Ward.*

I'm open to correction from the OP if this is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think FF put this information in a 'comment'? This is trivialising the site; an educated 10-year-old would be able to deduce this. And yes, OP should make absolutely sure 'I'm open to correction from the OP if this is incorrect' is unhelpful). They should phone the hospital / surgery involved.

Answer (score -1):

A Google search ([MS Excel database](https://www.plymouthhospitals.nhs.uk/download.cfm?doc=docm93jijm4n7840.xlsx&ver=10962)) shows that "Bracken ward" and "Meavy ward" are wards in Derriford Hospital, Plymouth, UK.

Edit to add:

OED

> **Ward** (noun) **18.a. An apartment or division in a hospital or lunatic asylum, containing a certain number of beds, or allocated to a particular class of patients.**
>
> 1739   J. Sparrow tr. H. F. Le Dran Observ. Surg. lxiii. 217   *He was lodged in the Fever Ward.*
>
> 1842   C. Dickens Amer. Notes I. vi. 221   *The different wards [of the lunatic asylum] might have been cleaner and better ordered.*
>
> 1982   B. Trapido Brother of More Famous Jack xlvii. 193   *I was required, during the first three months, to spend occasional week-long spells in hospital in a special ward for the observation of problem pregnancies.*

Comment: That doesn't answer the question which is "What does ward No mean?"  _ If you add that information, this will be a good answer.